# Ayuda consulta MySql

Tags: mysql

Estoy probando unas consultas y no consigo que una me funcione. Necesito obtener la *lista de pedidos* cada uno de los cuales *con el nombre del transportista asociado*. Solo tengo 8 pedidos por lo que debería tener 8 resultados pero me devuelve bastantes más...

*SQL crear tablas:*

```
CREATE TABLE carriers (
  id_carrier  int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name        varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE orders (
  id_order    int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  reference   varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_carrier  int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE orders
  ADD UNIQUE(reference),
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_carrier) REFERENCES carriers(id_carrier);
```

*SQL inserts para las pruebas:*

```
INSERT INTO carriers ( id_carrier , name ) VALUES
(NULL, 'test'),
(NULL, 'seur'),
(NULL, 'asm'),
(NULL, 'xxx');

INSERT INTO orders ( id_order, reference, id_carrier ) VALUES
(NULL, 'XKBKNABJK', 1),
(NULL, 'OHSATSERP', 2),
(NULL, 'UOYEVOLIT', 2),
(NULL, 'FFATNOMMJ', 1),
(NULL, 'KHWLILZLL', 4),
(NULL, 'ZRIIQDSYN', 1),
(NULL, 'DGAJIPUWH', 3),
(NULL, 'RTJHJMRAC', 3);
```

Estaba probando diferentes combinaciones con lo siguiente:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    id_order AS Pedido, 
    reference AS Referencia, 
    carriers.name AS Servicio 
        FROM orders, carriers 
        WHERE orders.id_carrier IN (SELECT id_carrier FROM carriers) 

    /*GROUP BY orders.id_order, Servicio*/
    ORDER BY orders.id_order ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Nada, encontre la forma de hacerlo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    id_order AS Pedido, 
    reference AS Referencia, 
    carriers.name AS Servicio 
        FROM orders, carriers 
        WHERE orders.id_carrier = carriers.id_carrier

    ORDER BY orders.id_order ASC;
```

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

Buenas
Prueba a realizar un left join en lugar de simplemente mostrar las dos tablas:

```
SELECT id_order AS Pedido, reference AS Referencia, carriers.name AS Servicio 
    FROM orders left join carriers on orders.id_carrier = carriers.id_carrier
    WHERE orders.id_carrier IN (SELECT id_carrier FROM carriers) 

/*GROUP BY orders.id_order, Servicio*/
ORDER BY orders.id_order ASC
```

De esta forma puedes incluso retirar el DISTINCT, ya que no tomará filas duplicadas para orders.

Answer (score 0):

Esta consulta tiene una forma bien básica y natural de resolverse

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    o.id_order AS Pedido, 
    o.reference AS Referencia, 
    c.carriers.name AS Servicio 
    FROM orders o
    LEFT JOIN carriers c
       ON c.id_carrier = o.id_carrier 
    ORDER BY o.id_order ASC
```

Recuperamos todas las ordenes y relacionamos cada una (1 a 1) con el único transportista que podría tener. Si un orden no tuviera transportista el `LEFT JOIN` nos asegura que la va a mostrar de todas formas.